# Ruby, swapping element in hash for iterating purpose

Tags: ruby, loops, hash, element, swap

How to swap element in a hash?

Example I have this hash :

```
my_hash = { 1 => [100,200,300], 2 => [10, 20, 30], 3 => [1000, 2000, 3000], }
```

I want to change it into like this :

```
my_hash = { 2 => [10, 20, 30], 1 => [100,200,300], 3 => [1000, 2000, 3000], }
```

For example element one and two has been swapped, and the value for both keys are following it's key too.

Is there any way to do it? Thank you very much

EDIT : I want to iterate the hash with #each method, and the key that would be iterated first is important. I mean the first hash, key 1 will be iterated first, but after swapped(the second has) the key 2 would be iterated first.

Comment: If you mean the order when iterating them, specify that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
a = my_hash.to_a
a[0], a[1] = a[1], a[0]
Hash[a] # => {2 => [10, 20, 30], 1 => [100,200,300], 3 => [1000, 2000, 3000]}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to sort the hash values in ascending order.

```
 [10,20,30], [100,200,300] and [1000, 2000,3000]
```

If so then I suggest you in the below way

```
Hash[my_hash.sort { |x,y| x[1] <=> y[1] }]
```

Comment: A shorter way to write the same thing would be `Hash[my_hash.sort_by(&:last)]`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as follows. Note that prior to Ruby 1.9 there was no concept of the order of hash elements.

```
def reorder_hash(hash, key_order)
  Hash[key_order.zip(hash.values_at(*key_order))]
end 

my_hash = {a: [100,200,300], b: [10,20,30], c: [1000,2000,3000]}

reorder_hash(my_hash, [:b, :a, :c])
  #=> {b: [10,20,30], a: [100,200,300], c: [1000,2000,3000]}
reorder_hash(my_hash, my_hash.keys.reverse)
  #=> {c: [1000,2000,3000], b: [10,20,30], a: [100,200,300]}
```

You could add:

```
def swap_hash_pairs(hash, k1, k2)
  keys = hash.keys
  i1, i2 = keys.index(k1), keys.index(k2)
  keys[i1], keys[i2] = keys[i2], keys[i1]
  reorder_hash(hash, keys)
end

swap_hash_pairs(my_hash, :a, :b)
  #=> {b: [10,20,30], a: [100,200,300], c: [1000,2000,3000]}
swap_hash_pairs(my_hash, :a, :c)
  #=> {c: [1000,2000,3000], b: [10,20,30], a: [100,200,300]}
```